# Question about function generator's arbitrary waveform generation ability

Tags: function-generator

I want to buy a function generator with arbitrary waveform generation ability for lab use. My question is, can arbitrary waveform generation's capability generate one sine wave(act as noise) rides on a different frequency sine wave(act as signal). I want to use this capability to study filters.

Comment: What does it say in the brochure?

Comment: Some generators can AM or FM modulate signals or possibly you can sum two signals externally to get the combination you want.  Long arbritary waveforms are harder to store and may be easier for you to synthesize on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Depends on the unit. Basic units allow playback of one waveform at a time. This means that you could construct an arbitrary waveform with two frequency components and play it back, but you could have issues with repitition if the frequencies do not share a common factor. More advanced units can add two or more waveforms together on the same output port. One of these will definitely do what you want.

Comment: In the end, if it holds up to the "arbitrary" part, you can upload whatever waveforms you want to those, so even if it has no combining feature, you can do it outside the device.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the arbitrary part is usually fixed length, so you can't generate an arbitrary waveform with two arbitrary frequency components abd have it play back with no aberrations. If the frequencies are related by a rational fraction, you're ok. Otherwise, there will be a discontinuity at the end of the buffer.

Comment: in my experience, when the awg has enough memory, the frequency components caused by that are usually negligible, since if you were working on something where they are not, you would probably have the budget for a better awg ^^